# How to properly limit access of an IP to a certain time of day on a Netgear R7000P router

Tags: router, security, wifi-configuration, access-control

I am pulling my hair out trying to set up what I thought was a simple thing:  At bedtime, block internet for my 10-year-old's laptop, a school-issued Chromebook.  I don't have the ability to install apps or software on the device, so I thought that the easiest way would be to turn off the router's connection to her device at bedtime.

The mystery is that this process worked FINE for my phone when I tested, but it is NOT working for her computer despite my (I swear) doing exactly the same procedure.  (And yes, I know this is part of a bigger discussion about proper use of devices and being willing to turn them off at bedtime...we're having that chat, too, but I'd also like to just have it shut off as it's supposed to be able to.  If only to have the satisfaction of making it work!)

So...my steps were:

1. Give the laptop a static LAN IP.  192.168.0.25
2. Allow the device. (I default to block all devices...)
3. In the Access Control section, I have this IP added, and "Per Schedule" clicked.
4. In the Schedule, I have blocking starting at 19:30 and ending at 23:59, every day.

I've verified that the laptop indeed is using 192.168.0.25 as its IP.  When I added my phone and switched it to wifi only the internet stopped right at 19:30...but this infernal Chromebook chugs on, apparently oblivious to the machinations and traps I've set for it.  I have done web searches to places I am sure she's never gone and doubt that her Chromebook is set up to have cached the entire internet for use offline.  It just seems to be connected, no matter what the router's settings are.

I CAN block it by not allowing the IP.  But I want her to have access during the day.  So that's really not ideal.  Why on earth isn't this thing working for the scheduled access?!

I have no idea why this isn't working as expected, but would love to have a simple, easy way to turn her internet off at 7:30pm.  Unfortunately, as it's a school-issued computer I don't have any admin power to install anything on her device.  It seemed the router option would be a slam dunk but alas, not yet.

The router is a Netgear R7000P with current firmware, V1.3.1.64_10.1.36.

Thank you in advance for any help and suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

The answer turned out to be that the router for some reason didn't have automatic NTP and thought it was in a different time zone.  Once I selected that things worked.  This is solved.

Comment: Haha, so many acronyms, so little time.  Changed it to NTP.  Thank you!